# How to typecast void to struct/union to access fields?

Tags: c

I am getting the error, "Member reference base type 'void' is not a structure or union", when trying to print out a field of a structure I created.

This is the for loop that increments through a singly-linked lists nodes so long as the node is not null:

```
for (NODE *temp = sList->head; temp!=NULL;temp=temp->next){
        printf("DocNo: %d \n",*(int)temp->dataPtr->docNum);
    }
```

My `NODE` structure looks as follows (contains the `dataPtr` field):

```
typedef struct node{ //node structure definition (the individual nodes in the list)
    void* dataPtr;
    struct node* next;
} NODE;
```

My `PRINTJOB` struct (contains the `docNum` field):

```
typedef struct printJob{
    int docNum;
    int requestPri;
    int pageNums;
    int numCycles;
} PRINTJOB;
```

Additionally, I created a pointer to the `PRINTJOB` structure and populated the fields with values, and then called an `insertList()` function that takes a pointer to a created list, and the pointer to a populated `PRINTJOB` structure.

How do I access the fields of `PRINTJOB`?

Comment: So does `temp->dataPtr` actually point to a `struct printJob`?

Comment: If so, you want `printf("DocNo: %d\n", ((struct printJob *)temp->dataPtr)->docNum);`

Comment: Yes I am fairly certain it does as stepping through the debugger shows that the linkages are being assigned correctly.

When I print it out, it returns the address of the struct printJob as well.

Comment: The address of a struct is the address for its first member. So the address of each list node is the address of (e.g. a pointer to) a `struct printJob` Note above how @SteveSummit uses `(...)` around the cast and node to ensure proper operator precedence before accessing the `docnum` member.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, `temp` is a pointer to a `NODE`. So `temp->dataPtr` is a pointer to `void *`. If now that data is in fact a pointer to a `PRINTJOB`, you need to tell the compiler about it, so you could do the following:

```
PRINTJOB * pj = (PRINTJOB *)temp->dataPtr;
int docNum = pj->docNum;
```

To do both in a single line, do it like you'd do it in algebra; replace `pj` with its definition from the first line, so `pj->docNum` becomes:

```
(PRINTJOB *)temp->dataPtr->docNum
```

But the problem here is that dereferencing a pointer has a higher precedence than casting, so what the compiler sees is actually the following:

```
(PRINTJOB *)(temp->dataPtr->docNum)
```

First dereference everything, then cast it. Yet that way you'd try to access `docNum` of the void pointer `dataPtr`, which will not work. So you need to use parenthesis to change the order of operations:

```
((PRINTJOB *)temp->dataPtr)->docNum
```

Now the compiler first does one derference, then the cast, and finally another derefence. There is no need to cast to `int`, the compiler knows that `docNum` of a `PRINTJOB` is of type `int`.