# How to reference values of structure from variable of a different structure?

Tags: c, structure

Sorry if the title is a little confusing, as a beginner to C I really didn't know how else to put it. So I'm trying to create a singly linkedlist where each node not only has a pointer to the next node, but also a pointer to sub-linkedlist that starts from that node. Basically each node has its own linkedlist. In trying to create this LL, I've got a struct that houses characteristics of what each node should have, such as a pointer to the next node and a pointer to the linkedlist of data that stems from it. I've heard that you're actually able to make a struct of a struct. I want to make a second struct that structures the types of data that the node is holding:

```
struct NODE{
    void* data;
    struct Node* next;
}NODE;

typedef struct stuff{
    int data1;
    int data2;
    int data3;
}STUFF;
```

My question now, is that say I have a node from struct NODE like "NODE* node", how would I reference this node's types of data (data1, data2, etc)? I've tried casting, but not sure if I'm doing it wrong but something like this:

```
(STUFF)node->data1= DATA1; 
//where DATA1 is of course already defined to be some int
```

I did this inside of a function, and I get the error "Assignment to cast is illegal, lvalue casts are not supported".

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by this "sub-linked-list".  You seem to be describing something of type `struct stuff`, except that does _not_ look like a list node.  Are you trying to pack this structure inside a `void*`?  Please construct an example list and its contents to illustrate what you're trying to do.  It sounds like you want a linked list where the `data` member of each node points to another `struct NODE` (as the sub-list) and each of _those_ nodes have their `data` member point to a `struct stuff` value.  Is that correct?

Comment: what is the difference between NODE and Node types? Where is Node defined?

Comment: Basically I wanted to create a singly linkedlist where, compared to a basic LL each node only has just 1 piece of data, this LL has nodes that have multiple pieces of data (data1, data2, etc.)

Comment: then why dont you use a pointer of type STUFF instead of void?

Comment: Are you a classmate of @uwu?  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70140745/how-to-typecast-void-to-struct-union-to-access-fields).

Comment: Maybe? Everyone on here is anonymous. That link did help me though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concerning your cast problem... Here is how you could do it.

```
typedef struct Node{
    void* data;
    struct Node* next;
}NODE;

typedef struct stuff{
    int data1;
    int data2;
    int data3;
}STUFF;

int main()
{
    NODE *n = malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    n->data = malloc(sizeof(STUFF));
    STUFF *s = n->data;
    s->data1 = 15;
    printf("%d", ((STUFF*) n->data)->data1);
    return 0;
}
```